# Airflow : Error while adding python dependency

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, jaydebeapi

I am trying to add `jaydebeapi` into Airflow (hosted on Google Cloud Composer) via `Install pypi packages` functionality. Below is the configuration:

Airflow Version : 1.10.1 
jaydebeapi version : 1.1.1 (tried with 0.2.0 as well)
python version : 3

Once the update command finishes, Airflow UI returns 502 and composer shows the below error message:

> Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage:
>   TP_DEPLOYMENT_UPDATING response_timestamp { seconds: 1560444752 nanos:
>   292000000 } ]

Looks like it's a version conflict between Airflow's python version and `jaydebeapi`?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Jaydebeapi extensively for the past few years will all the last versions, without any issue.
I would recommend installing using their recommended package though:

```
pip install apache-airflow[jdbc]
```

from https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html